# is not assignable to android.app.activity fragment

Tags: android

I'm working on tab menu.So I create `Fragment` pages and adapter.When I add fragment pages to manifest It say "is not assignable to android.app.activity".So I switch to `FragmentActivity` from `Fragment` but this time I got the new error "cannot be converted to `Fragment`".

What should I do.I'm really tired.I also clean project and cache but isn't working.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabdene, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    testtab1 tab1 = new testtab1();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    testtab2  tab2 = new testtab2();
                    return tab2;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "FREE";
                case 1:
                    return "PAID";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Testtab1 same code as tab2 just different name.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class testtab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View pView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_testtab1, container ,false);
        return pView;
    }



}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".acilisbir">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".Ucretsiz">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data android:scheme="activityucretsiz" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AnaEkran">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data android:scheme="activityanaekran" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Login">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data android:scheme="activitylogin" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Arsiv">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data android:scheme="activityarsiv" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Inputlar" />
    <activity android:name=".Register" />
    <activity android:name=".Buy" />
    <activity android:name=".ucretli" />

    <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="[ca-app-pub-3384720584226622~3587918385]" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".tabdene"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tabdene"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>

    <activity android:name=".testtab1" />
</application>
```

Comment: You don't add fragments to the manifest, only activities. The activity with your tab menu will have to load the fragments through code based on which tab is selected.

Comment: I found te error.Problem is my xml file.I chose "activity" when I create the new activity.Now I create fragment activty and ti's work.It's taken a 3 days to see what I'm missed.But now works good.Also you right I shouldn't add to fragments on manifest.